# Cut out part of a matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have a square matrix A of size N. I would obtain, from A, a square matrix B of size N-d (where d is an integer greater than or equal to 1) such that

```
B[i,j]=A[i+d,j+d]
```

for each i,j=1,...,N-d.

This should means that, for d=1 we delete the first row and the column of Matrix A, for d=2 we delete the first two rows and columns of A and so on...

My solution is a simple double for cycle but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to perform this task.

Comment: extracting lower right of the matrix?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and an expected output for the same.

Comment: A[-(1:d), -(1:d)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to do this.

```
sub_matrix <- function(m, d, drop = FALSE){
    m_name <- deparse(substitute(m))
    n <- nrow(m)
    if(n != ncol(m)) stop("not a square matrix")
    if(missing(d) || is.null(d)) stop(paste(sQuote(d), "is missing or is NULL"))
    if(d > n) stop(paste(sQuote(d), "is greater than the dim of", sQuote(m_name)))
    inx <- seq_len(n)[-seq_len(d)]
    m[inx, inx, drop = drop]
}

a <- matrix(1:25, 5)

sub_matrix(a, 2)
sub_matrix(a, 4)
sub_matrix(a, 4, drop = TRUE)
sub_matrix(a, 5)

sub_matrix(a, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

**This works:**

```
# Reproductible Data:
A <- diag(6)
diag(A) <- 1:6
N <- 6

# Cut off point
d <- 1

# Cut
B <- A[(1+d):N, (1+d):N]


> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    6
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    3    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    4    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    5    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    6
```

**If you want to make this into a function to maximise efficiency:**

```
matCutter <- function(a, d){
    N <- sqrt(length(a))
    b <- a[(1+d):N, (1+d):N]
    return(b)
    }

matCutter(A, 1)
```

*Side note: I find it interesting to see different appraoches that people use for the same problem in R - a very good illustration of the expression "there's more than one way to skin a cat" - I've compared `sub_matrix` and `matCutter` functions that Rui and I provide; run time is about 9 times faster with `matCutter`.*

Answer (score -2):

To retrieve lower right triangular matrix, you can do as follows:

```
A <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
d <- 5
A[seq_len(nrow(A))[-seq_len(d)], seq_len(ncol(A))[-seq_len(d)], drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: @RussHyde solution is better!

Comment: this does not answer the question